# Nodejs different HMAC signature from OpenSSL

Tags: node.js, openssl, hmac, digest

I've been struggling with creating a correct HMAC signature in Node.

### Use case

I'm currently working a Jointspace API client for Node to control Philips smart tv's. But to get this working I need to sign a string for a pairing request.

### Current situation

My nodejs code looks like this:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

let secret = Buffer.from('ZmVay1EQVFOaZhwQ4Kv81ypLAZNczV9sG4KkseXWn1NEk6cXmPKO/MCa9sryslvLCFMnNe4Z4CPXzToowvhHvA==', 'base64');
let text = '12345';
let algorithm = 'sha1';
let hmac = crypto.createHmac(algorithm, secret);
hmac.write(text);
hmac.end();

console.log(hmac.read('binary').toString('base64'));
```

When I run it, it results to this:

```
~ $ node test.js
DURLMkx7YdrIlWdUKo3iNDC3cp0=
```

### Expected

When I do the exact same thing with the `openssl` command via the command line, I get a different result. (The correct result)

```
~ $ echo -n "ZmVay1EQVFOaZhwQ4Kv81ypLAZNczV9sG4KkseXWn1NEk6cXmPKO/MCa9sryslvLCFMnNe4Z4CPXzToowvhHvA==" | base64 -d | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac "12345" -binary | base64
GvbRLlBSY8r/jPqUGox8zZHxOew=
```

### References

There is [an issue on the node Github page](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5499) which addresses an issue of a difference between Node and openssl. In that issue they basically say that crypto in node is just a wrapper for the C++ openssl library. And in order for it to properly work you need to provide the secret as a Buffer instead of a string because of conversion issues.

E.g.

```
crypto.createHmac('sha1', new Buffer('secret_key', 'utf8'));
```

But this does not resolve my issue.

### Differences in output

```
~ $ echo "DURLMkx7YdrIlWdUKo3iNDC3cp0=" | base64 -d | hexdump -C
00000000  0d 44 4b 32 4c 7b 61 da  c8 95 67 54 2a 8d e2 34  |.DK2L{a...gT*..4|
00000010  30 b7 72 9d                                       |0.r.|
00000014
~ $ echo "GvbRLlBSY8r/jPqUGox8zZHxOew=" | base64 -d | hexdump -C
00000000  1a f6 d1 2e 50 52 63 ca  ff 8c fa 94 1a 8c 7c cd  |....PRc.......|.|
00000010  91 f1 39 ec                                       |..9.|
00000014
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your command you're using `12345` as the HMAC key but in your code you're using it as data! so here's an update on the code

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

let secret = 'ZmVay1EQVFOaZhwQ4Kv81ypLAZNczV9sG4KkseXWn1NEk6cXmPKO/MCa9sryslvLCFMnNe4Z4CPXzToowvhHvA=='
let key = '12345';
let algorithm = 'sha1';
let hmac = crypto.createHmac(algorithm, key);
hmac.write(secret);
hmac.end();

console.log(hmac.read('binary').toString('base64'));
```

And here's the command

```
echo -n "ZmVay1EQVFOaZhwQ4Kv81ypLAZNczV9sG4KkseXWn1NEk6cXmPKO/MCa9sryslvLCFMnNe4Z4CPXzToowvhHvA==" | openssl dgst -sha1 -hmac "12345" -binary | base64
```

They both return the same hash.